# Console UI with User input

Tags: c++, syntax, user-input

So i'm trying to make a simple console application that asks the user for certain characteristics. The first question, asks the user for their age. For example, it should look like "I am >enter age< years old" I've been having a lot of console application problems, so I'll probably be moving to GUI interfaces in the future.. Until then, I think this is good practice. Heres my code. (Sorry for not using the code format, it doesnt seem to work properly on my mobile)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//Variables
int Age;

 //Functions
int AgeEnt(){
cin >> Age;
return Age;
}

//Main
int main (){

    cout << "Welcome! Please enter  your age to continue\n";
    cout << "I am " << AgeEnt << "    years old";

return 0;
}
```

This automatically puts a 1 where the age should be. How would I make it to where I can input a number between the text? Im still a beginner so excuse me if this isnt possible in console, or extremely depreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main (){

cout << "Welcome! Please enter  your age to continue\n";
int age;
cin >> age;

return 0;
}
```

Also, why do you declare functions and variables above your main? Except for global functions, this is not needed in C++

Comment: I know how to request user input, however I dont want it to be just a new line istself. I want it to be on the lines of "I am "[TYPEAGE] " years old".    And I just do that for organization purposes

Comment: Haha sorry, let me further explain. I physically want to see on the console, "I am 'X' years old". X being what you type in. I guess what im really asking is how can i implement the cin function in between constant text? Hopefully that helps. I know how to use cin and cout, just not simultaneously on the same line in between 2 strings

Comment: In that case, I don't know... I also don't know how you will know the input is finished if the user cannot press enter...

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//Functions
int AgeEnt(){
    int Age;
    cin >> Age;
    return Age;
}

//Main
int main (){
    cout << "Welcome! Please enter  your age to continue\n";
    AgeEnt();
    cout << "I am " << AgeEnt() << "    years old";
    return 0;
}
```

A few things

1. You don't need the `<string>`  header file for this. Its not being used anywhere.
2. You don't need to declare `Age` as a global variable. Its only being used in one function so declare it in that.

Also, although i haven't done it here, i would usually do something like `int a = AgeEnt(); cout<<a;`